# Botao "enviar", verificar quantidade de dígitos na senha e se é igual a outra senha em html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou fazendo um formulário, onde o botão "enviar" dados precisa verificar a quantidade de dígitos e conferir se é igual a outra senha.

Código html

```
<div class="content">
   <input type="submit" class="botao01"  onclick="Salvar();" value="Salvar" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function Salvar(){
    var senha1 = document.f1.senha1.value;
    var senha2 = document.f1.senha2.value;

    if(senha1 === senha2){
        alert("SENHAS IGUAIS");
    }else{
        alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES");
    }
    if(senha.lenght>=6){
       alert("Dígitos minimo é 6");
    }
}
```

Mas não está conferindo...

Comment: Aline, revise a sua pergunta. O HTML está incompleto e não diz qual o objetivo da função `Salvar()` e como você está usando ela. Além do que existem erros, como a variável `senha` que não existe e se você quer que tenha no mínimo 6 caracteres, o correto seria usar `<6` (menor que 6) e não `>=6` (maior ou igual a 6).

Comment: <div class="input-div" id="input-senha1"><b>Senha:</b>
                <input type="password"  required id="senha1" name="senha1" placeholder="Insira senha "  />
            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá:

1. Evite usar `onclick` direto no HTML, essa utilização é muito antiga e desencorajada hoje em dia, faça a criação do listener direto no JS.
2. Não acesse os elementos direto como está tentando (`document.f1.senha1....`), utilize a busca padrão do JS que é mais garantida, seja pelo id (`document.getElementById`) ou até mesmo pelo querySelector (`document.querySelector("...")`)
3. Para que seja obrigado a digitar pelo menos 6 dígitos, use `length < 6` (tamanho **menor que** 6) e faça essa verificação antes das demais, assim se não tiver o mínimo de caracteres, nem precisa verificar se são iguais, pois já são inválidas mesmo...

No código abaixo, pode conferir tudo que comentei acima em um exemplo funcional.

```js
document.getElementById("botaoSalvar").onclick = Salvar;

function Salvar(){
  var senha1 = document.getElementById("senha1").value;
  var senha2 = document.getElementById("senha2").value;

  if(senha1.length < 6 || senha2.length < 6){
     console.log("Dígitos minimo é 6");
     return;
  }

  if(senha1 === senha2){
     console.log("SENHAS IGUAIS");
  }else{
      console.log("SENHAS DIFERENTES");
      return;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="input-div" id="input-senha1">
      <b>Senha:</b> 
      <input type="password" required id="senha1" name="senha1" placeholder="Insira senha..." />
      <input type="password" required id="senha2" name="senha2" placeholder="Senha novamente..." />
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" class="botao01" id="botaoSalvar" value="Salvar" />
  </div>
```